# Update function in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

This is my app.component.ts file where I have created my add and delete functions

```
export class AppComponent 
{   
   title = 'organizer';
   items = [];  
   newItem = '';

   pushItem = function() {
       if (this.newItem !== ''){
           this.items.push(this.newItem);
           this.newItem = '';
         }   
   };

  removeItem = function(index){
    this.items.splice(index, 1);
  };
}
```

This is the html file where I have used the above methods

```
<div>
  <h1>Item's List</h1>
  <div class="addItem">
    <input [(ngModel)] = "newItem" placeholder="Add Item" class="addText">
    <button (click)="pushItem()">Add</button>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let i of items; let ind = index">
      {{i}}
      <span>update</span>
      <span (click)="removeItem(ind)">x</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to add a update method to this application.The entered data should be displayed in the input panel when update is clicked and after updating and clicking the add button the data should be updated .

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could turn the simple string value into an object with a `key` and a `value`. This way you can identify your items and update them accordingly.

Comment: put your update function to in your code please.